# How to extract column from excel file?

Tags: python

What be the best method to extract a column set of data? I have Matlab code for this data analysis, but I want to use Python.

[Excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4h5O.jpg)
How would extract individual columns and put them into a column vector in Python? For example, say I want to extract column B, rows 3 to 26. 
The code for reading in the excel file is below:

```
# importing libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# reads in excel data
cylinder_data_file = pd.ExcelFile('FriDataCylinder.xlsx')
cylinder_data_file.sheet_names
data = cylinder_data_file.parse('Sheet1')
```

I am using Python 3.6 as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understand your question, but given a `pandas.DataFrame` `df`, you can slice a column by using the column label

```
column = df.column_label
```

or the column integer index.

```
column = df.iloc[:, 2]
```

You could create a list of columns with

```
column_list.append(column)
```

and finally create a new `DataFrame` by concatenating the list like

```
new_df = pd.concat(column_list)
```

If you want a more in-depth answer, you will need to provide some data.

Comment: I made some adjustments to my question and added an image of the data.